# Ravendb dynamically build index

Tags: ravendb

I'm building a project with Ravendb. The current issue is object references. For instance. I have two documents. One is Person with Name, Age, Gender. Gender will reference to Gender document. We will have a form to help user modify values.

So the person document will keep the ID of Gender object. Whenever Gender is updated, we will have the latest gender value.

My current approach, in Person form, i will keep all references. When engine render the form, it will have own data for render. But when the gender updating, i don't know how to update relevant documents.

I'm really appreciated answers and suggestions.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to model things in RavenDB using an extremely relational model.
I wouldn't suggest it. Please read about document based modeling.

Comment: Thanks for  your feedback.